# java.util.Scanner doesn't read empty line

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, readfile

I wrote a .txt file in which each line has a meaning - even an empty one. Scanner's methods next() and nextLine() do not recognize the empty line and jump right to the line with text. **I'm wondering if there is a way for the scanner to consider all lines of text regardless the content.**

I don't want to use BufferedReader because I'm working with very small tokens each time.

```
static final String fileName = "temp.txt";
    try {
            //System.out.println(Jsoup.connect(url).get());
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            Elements names = document.select("[id^=CZ]");
            for (Element name : names) {
                bufferedWriter.write(name.text());
                bufferedWriter.write(System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator());
                System.out.println(name.text() + '\n');
            }
            bufferedWriter.close();
           Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
           in.next();
           String s = names.first().text();
           String h = in.next();

           ...
```

At this point Strings s & h should be equal.

The document the scanner is reading starts with an empty line and goes like this:

> *asdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkdsasdkjasjkdajkdahkdjahdjadhkahdajkdajkds*

Again, I have a dynamic file that might have first line empty and when I compare String **s** with String **h** they DO NOT equal. nextLine() and next() skip over the first line while it is still a valid element.

Comment: Please read the [mcve] link, and then create and post one, together with a small representation of your text file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can ya please post your code?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/Q1Y25z

Comment: Scanner does read empty lines also. Please add your code in the question.

Comment: It is obvious that `next()` doesn't read empty lines, but reading its JavaDoc is way too hard for some people. And that `nextLine` doesn't read an empty line, is a blatant lie.

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` is the method that you need. Unlinke `next()`, it does not skip ahead through newlines and white space.

Run this example ([demo](http://ideone.com/qSsfzb))

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("'"+s+"'");
}
```

on input with empty lines to see that these lines are preserved:

```
'quick brown'
''
'fox jumps'
'over'
''
'the'
''
'lazy dog'
```

Comment: `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()` was the change I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` method reads tokens seperated by `whitespaces` or `newline` characters on other hand `nextLine()` reads lines seperated by `newline` charater.

You can try this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```